# Moved site , all links got corrupted, need correct SQL query to fix

Tags: sql, mariadb

Wordpress. from litespeed to ngix server.

All of my links to plugins, images CSS and scripts added "%20" on the end. Example:

https://example.com%20/wp-content/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/assets/css/style.min.css?

I assume the solution would be to change all "example.com%20" to "example.com" in the database. What would be the correct query to put in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the solution would be to change all "example%20" to "example" in the database.

You can use `replace()`:

```
update t
    set link = replace(link, 'example%20', 'example')
    where link like '%example$%20%' escape '$';
```

You have to be a little careful if `'example%20'` were ever in the data *before* the change (i.e. is correct).  However, that is unlikely in this case.

Comment: Thanks. so update t would be the table to update? do I need to do it for every single table or is there a way to change all at once?

Comment: not specifying gives that it doesn't exist, specifying table gives   #1054 - Unknown column 'link' in 'field list'

Comment: @Andoriod . . . `t` is the name of the table you are updating.  `link` is my best guess on your column name.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, was a trailing space in wp-config.